# android recyclerview sticky header with checkbox

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sticky

I have tested timehop/superslim and some other libraries but can not find the desired solution. I need to place a checkbox in sticky header but the above libraries does not support for click listener for child view in header because it copies and draw the header pixel by pixel.

Kindly suggest me some other library that help me for the desired solution

[see the image for desired solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNc6g.png)

BR

Answer (score 0):

Try

**1.** Add following dependency

```
compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.1.5'
```

**2.** Implement `StickyListHeadersAdapter` in your adapter and override `getHeaderView` & `getView` methods

```
BaseAdapter implements StickyListHeadersAdapter
```

**3.** Add following list view to your layout

```
<se.emilsjolander.stickylistheaders.StickyListHeadersListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clipToPadding="false"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="false"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:scrollIndicators="none"
    android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:visibility="visible" />
```

**4.** Create adapter object and set listview adapter

```
    StickyListHeadersListView stickyList = (StickyListHeadersListView) findViewById (R.id.list);
    stickyList.setDrawingListUnderStickyHeader (true);
    stickyList.setAreHeadersSticky (true);
    stickyList.setAdapter (yourAdapter);
```

https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders

Comment: kindle give me the solution in recyclerview